# React Native: Android activity go back

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I implemented android native module from [Bambora SDK](https://developer.bambora.com/europe/native-payment/android/registering-cards) and displayed its native view(activity) by `getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent);`

It works like a charm but `finish()` makes whole app quit instead of going back. Here are some of my codes.

```
public class ToastModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    @ReactMethod
    // Calling module function from ReactJS code and works well
    public void goToRegisterCardView(Callback callback) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getCurrentActivity(), NativeCardRegistrationActivity.class);
        getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent); //start Activity successfully
    }
    ...
}

public class NativeCardRegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ICardRegistrationCallback {
    @Override
    public void onRegistrationSuccess(CreditCard creditCard) {
        finish();// Exit whole app instead of going back.
    }
    ...
}
```

So I'm sure it's not a reason from **Bambora SDK** and `finish()` kills `NativeCardRegistrationActivity`. The whole app is killed because there is no activity in `Activity Stack`.
Because I'm not familiar with Java code, I'm not able to figure out what the reason is here.

Please let me know what's wrong and how I can go back to original react-native activity.

**Update

Here is my MainApplication.java codes

```
public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

  // Needed for `react-native link`
  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
//      new MainReactPackage(),
      new AnExampleReactPackage(this)
    );
  }
}
```

Currently, I commented `new MainReactPackage()` for temporarily and it doesn't occur error, but if I remove the comment to enable `new MainReactPackage()` then, I can see error with red background.

Please check this.
[ReactNative: Android Native Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275243/react-native-android-native-module)