# React Native: Android Native Module

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I implemented a native module on the React Native / Android Project.
In the Android native project, I used startActivity function to move to the new activity I created manually.
I will share some of the codes.

```
//MainApplication.java

public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
  ...
  // Needed for `react-native link`
  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new AnExampleReactPackage(this)
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

Here, if I use the code `new MainReactPackage()` then I see the error while running the app on my Android device.

> Native module AccessibilityInfoModule tried to override
> AccessibilityInfoModule for module name AccessibilityInfo. If this was
> your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true

But I'm not sure how I can set the `canOverrideExistingModule`.
How can I solve this?

Relative Question: [React Native: Android activity go back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253118/react-native-android-activity-go-back)

Answer (score 1):

Check your

> MainApplication.java

(under .\android\app\src\main\java\com\projectName)
To see if you have the duplicate declarations in method getPackages().

and also check in import.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to override AccessibilityInfoModule? If yes then simply add this to your NativeModule class

```
@Override    
public boolean canOverrideExistingModule() {        
  return true;    
}
```

Comment: where could i find NativeModuleClass?

Comment: Yeah, Where do you put this?